# How to reset additional partition ownership and permissions to default in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-11, icacls

***How do you set/reset a partition's default ownership and security permissions in Windows 11?***

For example, there might be `Creator Owner`, or `Trusted Installer`, etc...

This is especially important when configuring storage locations for users' documents, etc.

I am hoping for a solution that will ***help after `Reset`ing a Windows installation***—when there are already owners and permissions assigned to a pre-existing partition.  Perhaps through the installer's command line, (for fixing Recycle Bin folders, etc.)?

Thanks!

Comment: Partitions other than the system disk should by default be accessible to all users. Is this permissions problem something you are actively facing?

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes, it is always an issue when reinstalling Windows with data on other partitions that has to be kept.  And it's not just being accessible to users where the problem lies.  System installations, and the creation of User folders as well...  There should be default Owner/Permissions scheme define "someplace", but I just can't find it—let alone how to apply it to the partition.

Comment: To **reset** a folder and subfolders/files completely to system defaults, you could use `icacls "x:\path\to\folder" /reset /t /c /l`, but your mention of User folders makes me think there may be a better way to do what you're looking for. Can you add more detail about this situation to your question?